# Is it possible to set classic ASP settings for IIS from a web.config file?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, web-config

We are running IIS 7.5 and we'd like to be able to set the IIS classic ASP "Enable Session State" variable from our web.config file.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, give some details?

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft's documentation on the `sessionState` element? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @RobertSimpson That's ASP.Net session state, don't confuse the issue further.

Comment: Yes sir, Mr. English Colonel, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty straightforward.

Here is an example taken from [IIS.Net - ASP Session](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session)

```
<system.webServer>
  <asp>
    <session allowSessionState="true" max="1000" timeout="00:10:00" />
  </asp>
</system.webServer>
```

---

As a side note, if the `web.config` approach doesn't work for your circumstance you can always enable session state at the page level in Classic ASP by passing the processing directive

```
<%@ ENABLESESSIONSTATE = True %>
```

as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910356/is-it-possible-to-set-classic-asp-settings-for-iis-from-a-web-config-file#comment73095260_42912281) by [@kul-tigin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893670/kul-tigin)

Comment: That did the trick. Sadly, in our case the ASP settings were locked by a parent so it didn't work without manually modifying settings on the server, something we were trying to avoid. Aside from that though, thanks. Your solution is correct in respect of the question I asked.

Comment: @MichaelBaker It's the default configuration, sad. Do you know that you can disable session state per page by putting a directive? In case you don't know I leave a link here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525847(v=vs.90).aspx